# Simplest way to implement a timer event in Java

Tags: java, android, events, timer, java-7

Im looking for a way to implement a timer event in Java SE 1.7, I don't want to use Swing timers as I have plans to port this application to Android.

---

**Background**

Im writing  a LoginSession class that should generate an event when the session times out - this event should then be handled by a SessionManager class.

I presume this a common enough requirement -I would  expect there be a simple built in support for this but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* simple built-in support.  Use [Timer.schedule()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date%29).

Comment: +1 Looks simple -so basically the timer event handler will be a class that extends TimerTask ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  TimerTask implements Runnable, so it's pretty trivial.