# How to call method in every minute using Java but in background without affect current process?

Tags: java, background, task

When program will be started then automatically call one method in every minute in background without using thread.

```
class Abc
{
    main()
    {
        do something......
    }
}
class xyz
{
    public void show()
    {
         call every 1 minute in background
         do something.....
         with out affect main method
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest way to implement a timer event in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641957/simplest-way-to-implement-a-timer-event-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do 2 things at one time with only 1 thread. You have to create another thread.

Comment: is this possible in jsp servlet or not? if servlet or jsp is running and in background one servlet is execute with out affecting current file.

Comment: Servlets are being initialized in a container like tomcat for example. Each time there's an invocation of a servlet method, the container creates a new thread in the background for that service. I don't understand what do you mean by saying that it doesn't effect current file. What file?

Comment: means when a.jsp or a.java is already running on browser, so now every 5 minute b.java file is run in background without affect a.jsp or a.java. a.jsp file output is display on browser and after 5 minute b.java file is run but user side only display a.jsp file output. any java file or any user method which is run in background without display user side some task may perform in background. is it possible or not using jsp servlet?

Comment: It is possible, but to do this you have to create another thread. You have to create a class which implements runnable and override the run method. In the run method you make an infinite loop and add the sleep method somewhere inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need to call show() every 1 min from main without interfering main() code

```
class Abc
{
    main()
    {
        Thread mythread = new Thread()
         {
            xyz myClass = new xyz();
            public void run()
            {
              while(true)
              {
                    myClass.show() // this will execute
                    thread.sleep(60000); // this will pause for a bit but wont affect your main code, add this in between try and catch to pause this thread alone withotu affecting main one for 1 min and it goes again and calls show()
               } 
            }
         }
        do something......            
    }
}
class xyz
{
    public void show()
    {
         // whatever you type here will now run every 1 min, without affecting your main code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) for this task.

```
public static class Scheduler {

        private Runnable task;
        private ScheduledExecutorService executorService;

        public Scheduler(Runnable task, ScheduledExecutorService executorService) {
          this.task = task;
          this.executorService = executorService;
        }

        public void start(long startDelay, long period ) {
          executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, startDelay, period, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
      }
```